# How to return whatever is returned from remote server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following WebClient code that is supposed my code acts as a proxy, and link to remote server, I would like to throw up whatever response that is returned from the remote server, how can I do so? I do not want to handle exceptions or anything, just merely throwing responses.

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";

    Uri NODE_LOGIN_PATH = new Uri(URI_Combine(NodeAPI, "auth/login"));
    string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login_details);


    JObject data = JObject.Parse(await client.UploadStringTaskAsync(NODE_LOGIN_PATH, jsonString));
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Show more context. What is `client`? What does the method you're in want you to return? Are you sure you want to return the entire response from your HTTP client, including headers (which may leak stuff the client can use to abuse your credentials)?

Comment: My current scenario is a Machine (MVC) that is meant for staff for logging documemt, and it will be connected to a NodeJS backend, weve developed the Frontend (Developed using Electron) and there are third party function that is only developed in ASP.Net, hence we are using MVC only for Web API purpose. Hence, I am hopping just to return whatever Node return (it will return 404 and etc which is meant for normal usage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using WebClient in an MVC 4 project, so you're on old stuff. Consider upgrading to HttpClient and ASP.NET Core.

The principle that you want goes something like this:

```
public class FooController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        // Do the HTTP call
        var httpResponse = client.DoSomeRequest();

        // Translate
        var apiResponse = new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode.Map(...),
            Headers = httpResponse.Headers.Map(...),
            Body = httpResponse.Body.Map(...),
        };


        // Return
        return apiResponse;
    }

}
```

So: do the request, and translate (map) it to the HttpResponseMessage (or IHttpActionResult, or ...) that your Web API platform requires.

Comment: Hi, just to let you know I've then been using httpclient, its been so much better!